# problem in parsing xml file from network database

Tags: android, url, inputstream, xml-parsing

in my app i am getting a xml file from a network database, i have only one error in my overall coding,

it shows error in the line where i have mention  the input,

i am mentioning the input as

`url = new InputStream(http://siva.com);`

it marks the word InputStream with red line and shows the error as `Cannot instantiate the type InputStream`

How to give the input of an URL, pls help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah, you can not instantiate InputStream, have a look at this: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html

> ```
> import java.net.*;
> import java.io.*;
> public class URLReader {
>     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
>     URL yahoo = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/");
>     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
>             new InputStreamReader(
>             yahoo.openStream()));
>     String inputLine;
>     while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
>         System.out.println(inputLine);
>     in.close();
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
URL url = new URL("http://siva.com");
URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();

InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream());
```

Answer (score 1):

Another go at it :-)

```
            // Send data
            URL url = new URL("##YOURURL##");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();

            // Get the response
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            line = rd.readLine();
            if(line != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            wr.close();
            rd.close();
```